# executeUpdate() always returns 1

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I am trying to edit rows from JSP page via AJAX call to a servlet which further goes to a edit function but the value of `k` is always 1.

Here is the servlet code :

```
try {
            k=obj.editportal(env, region, url, user, rnode, password,envid,attuid);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        System.out.println("value of k is = "+k);
        
         if(k==0)
          {
            res.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
            pw.write("Internal server error");
          } 
         else if(k==1)
          {
            res.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
            pw.write("Row updated Successfully");          
          }
```

Here is my Java function:

```
 try {
      Connection con = db.getConnection();
      String query = "update ENV_MOTS_DETAILS set " +
            "ENV_NAME= ? , CONSOLE_URL= ? , REMOTE_NODE= ? , CONSOLE_TO_LOGON=? , " +
            "REGION=? , DELETE_FLAG='Y' , ADMIN_PWD=? , " +
            "COMPONENT='' , COMMENTS='' , LAST_UPDATED_BY=?, " +
            "LAST_UPDATED_ON=to_date(to_char(SYSDATE,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') WHERE ENV_ID = ?";
      
      log.info("[Editconsole Method Call Query]"+query);
      
      ps = con.prepareStatement(query);
      
      ps.setString(1,env);
      ps.setString(2,url);
      ps.setString(3,rnode);
      ps.setString(4,user);
      ps.setString(5,region);
      ps.setString(6,password);
      ps.setString(7,attuid);
      ps.setInt(8,envid);
      
      ret=ps.executeUpdate();
      
      ps.close();
      //con.commit();
      con.close();
      
    } 
     catch (Exception e) 
     {
        log.fatal("[SQL Exception in retrieving Server Details]"+e.getMessage());
        throw e;
    }
     return ret;
  }
```

Sometimes it gives return value as `0` but that is rare. But once it returns `0`  it always gives `0` even if I re-enter correct entries,

Comment: So `ret` is 0/1 as well?

Comment: Btw, since `k == 0` would indicate an error (not quite correct though) then there just might be no "error" i.e. the update worked. When k is 0 then check whether a stacktrace is printed, i.e. you get an exception, print the stacktrace and continue with k having the value it had right before the try-block (which I assume to be 0).

Comment: mostly it is 1 on incorrect sql but rarely it gives 0 on that

Comment: No need for double type conversion; you can simply use `sysdate` to update a date column

Comment: @thomas .. i have a stack trace in logs where there is exception in logs `but k=1`

Comment: Please define _incorrect sql_. If the query works and the database updated a row (due to the where condition I assume it can be at most 1 row) then the result is correct. If you get 0 then the database probably didn't execute the query, couldn't find a row that matches the where condition or somehow didn't see any changes (although I'd doubt that).

Comment: As to your last anwer: that might mean k is altered or cached somehow. We'd need more info on how k is defined and used in that case.

Comment: incorrect means `java.sql.SQLException: ORA-12899: value too large for column "INFRAJEWL"."ENV_MOTS_DETAILS_NEW"."ADMIN_PWD"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error `java.sql.SQLException: ORA-12899: value too large for column "INFRAJEWL"."ENV_MOTS_DETAILS_NEW"."ADMIN_PWD"` is caused by

```
 ps.setString(6,password);
```

containing a string in `password` that's longer than the column `ADMIN_PWD` in your table is defined to hold.

Check the table definition and check your `password` length.

Return value 0 simply states: No rows updated, while return value 1 identifies "1" row updated. As your `ENV_ID` most likely is the primary key to your table it's absolutely okay you never see any other values.

**Note:** You can get 0 rows updated and the statement worked okay. That would be the case when *no data was changed* by the update (values same as before)

By writing it `try-with-resource` style, you could remove dependency on variable `ret` a bit more always returning 0 in case of Exception:

```
String query = "update ENV_MOTS_DETAILS set " +
        "ENV_NAME= ? , CONSOLE_URL= ? , REMOTE_NODE= ? , CONSOLE_TO_LOGON=? , " +
        "REGION=? , DELETE_FLAG='Y' , ADMIN_PWD=? , " +
        "COMPONENT='' , COMMENTS='' , LAST_UPDATED_BY=?, " +
        "LAST_UPDATED_ON=to_date(to_char(SYSDATE,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') WHERE ENV_ID = ?";

try(Connection con = db.getConnection();      
     ps = con.prepareStatement(query)) {
  log.info("[Editconsole Method Call Query]"+query);

  ps.setString(1,env);
  ps.setString(2,url);
  ps.setString(3,rnode);
  ps.setString(4,user);
  ps.setString(5,region);
  ps.setString(6,password);
  ps.setString(7,attuid);
  ps.setInt(8,envid);

  int numAffected = ps.executeUpdate();
  log.info("Statement affected " + numAffected + " rows");
  return 1; //Worked.

 } 
 catch (Exception e)  {
    log.fatal("[SQL Exception in retrieving Server Details]"+e.getMessage());
 }
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: this is exactly i want ... i want 0 when i enter a large value but i always get return value as 1

Comment: it means i can get return value as 1 even when 0 rows are updated ?

Comment: too mush of your code is missing to give a statement on that - but the code I gave would do that: return 0 in case of SQL errors, return 1 if SQL statement was accepted (no matter if it changed anything)

Comment: did you figure out a solution? Still need help?

Comment: i didnt ..this issue is as it is..tested on netbeans with glassfish server ,, same issue ... return value is 1 even with exception ..4 out of 20 times it is correct